# How to limit large messages in ActiveMQ Artemis (by size)

Tags: activemq-artemis

As we can limit paged messages by size using `page-limit-bytes`, is there any configuration for large-messages also? I can't find anywhere in the doc. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no setting to limit disk usage specifically for large messages, but there are general broker settings that would apply:

- `max-disk-usage` - This is the percentage of disk used. For example, if the disk’s capacity was 500GiB and `max-disk-usage` was `50` then the broker would start blocking producers once 250GiB of disk space was used.
- `min-disk-free` - This is specific amount and not a percentage like with max-disk-usage. For example, if the disk’s capacity was 500GiB and `min-disk-free` was `100GiB` then the broker would start blocking producers once 400GiB of disk space was used.

These are discussed on [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html#monitoring-disk).

Comment: Any plans to add something in future? This might be required where failure of consuming messages from one queue doesn't impact every queues

Comment: I'm not clear on the use-case you're describing. Feel free to open a [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS) with a full description.

Comment: Hey, raised one - [Artemis-4562](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4562)