# Messages silently getting dropped without any error to producers for disabled queues in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

For Disabled Queues in ActiveMQ Artemis , when Producers(Java/Dotnet) sending messages , the messages are getting dropped silently without any error to the producers due to which neither producers nor consumers aware that the Queue is in Disabled state . Could you please check if there is any way artemis can send error messages to producers/Consumers for Disabled queues .

We are expecting some kind of error for disabled queues when producers trying to send messages to the queue .

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior for a disabled queue. There is currently now way to change this behavior as it is hard-coded to silently drop the messages. [The documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#disabled-queue) specifically notes:

> Disabling all the queues on an address means that any message sent to that address will be silently dropped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but its very risky to disable the queues . The problem is producers are not able to know if the messages are getting dropped due to which lots of escalations happening . We are doing this to restrict Large messages as for Large messages also , there is no parameter to restrict producers due to which our storage getting full . We tried to put a logic for persistent-size of the queues and once it cross the assigned size to the queue , we are disabling the queues , but seems its very risky to do that  . Could you check if there is a way to restrict large messages .

Comment: Whether it's risky to disable queues depends entirely on your use-case. It may be risky for your use-case, but for other use-cases it would not be risky. Also, keep in mind that an address may have many queues and not all of them may be disabled so throwing an error back to the client is tricky because the message may, for example, get routed to 99 queues but fail to be routed to just 1 queue. Ultimately I think you're trying to use this functionality for a purpose for which it was not intended. Please ask a _new_ question about restricting large messages.

Comment: I want to simply restrict large message based on size . I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77785572/how-to-limit-large-messages-in-activemq-artemis-by-size) .

Comment: I have raised the below ticket for large messages[](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78223265/restrict-large-messages-to-artemis) , There should be something in place to restrict large messages per addresses . Its not good to impact all tenants in a broker for any issue with a single tenant .